# Javascript - countdown timer is incrementing not persecond

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

Can anyone tell me what am i doing wrong? i have the timer which is displaying with 2 or 3 or 4 seconds at once increment instead of per second.

```
var call_s = 0;
var call_m = 0;
var call_h = 0;
var call_connected = null;
var display = null ;
function connected_timer_start(tototo) {
  call_connected  = setTimeout(function() {
    call_s++;

    if (call_s>59) { 
      call_s = 0;
      call_m++;
    }

    if (call_m>59){
      call_m = 0;
      call_h++;
    }


    display = (call_h < 10 ? '0' : '') + call_h + ':' + 
                  (call_m < 10 ? '0' : '') + call_m  + ':' + 
                  (call_s < 10 ? '0' : '') + call_s;


    console.log(display);
    connected_timer_start();
  }, 1000);
}


function connected_timer_stop() {
  call_s = 0;
  call_m = 0;
  call_h = 0;
  clearTimeout(call_connected);
  call_connected = null;

  document.getElementById('display').style.display = 'none';
}
```

Comment: Works fine for me when I run it in a clean console.  Depending on when it starts because the next timer is set to run after calculations are performed, there will be a slight shift from second to second.  Any reason `setInterval` wasn't used?

Comment: FYI, you should never try to keep accurate time with `setTimeout()` because `setTimeout()` is not guaranteed to maintain an exact timing interval (its interval is approximate).  Instead, you can can use the timer to regularly get the current system time `var now  = new Date()` and display the time you get from the system.  This will also let you use all the methods from the `Date` object to get minutes, seconds, hours, etc...

Comment: How do you start the counter? The behaviour that you described can easily be reproduced by starting the counter several times at the same moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As jfriend00 said, you shouldn't use `setTimeout()` to figure out the time values, because it's not reliable. A version of code that uses `Date()` is actually shorter and simpler:

```
    var begining_timestamp = null;
    var call_connected = null;
    var call_ms = null;
    var display = null ;

    function connected_timer_start() {
        if (call_connected==null) {
            begining_timestamp = (new Date()).getTime();
            count();
        } else {
            console.log('One timer is already started!');
        }
    }

    function count() {
        call_connected  = setTimeout(function() {
            getCallLength();
            count();
        }, 1000);
    }

    function getCallLength() {
        call_ms = (new Date()).getTime() - begining_timestamp;
        var tmp_date = new Date(null);
        tmp_date.setSeconds(call_ms/1000);
        display = tmp_date.toISOString().substr(11, 8);
        console.log(display);
    }


    function connected_timer_stop() {
        clearTimeout(call_connected);
        getCallLength();
        call_connected = null;
        document.getElementById('display').style.display = 'none';
    }
```

I see several advantages to this approach:

- times are accurate even if setTimeout triggers every 2 seconds or at random times, your call duration will be accurate
- the call duration gets updated when the call ends, to make sure it's completely accurate
- you have the call time down to milliseconds, if you ever need that
- the `call_ms` variable does not get cleared when a call ends, but when a call starts; that means between two calls, you can always have the last call length expressed in milliseconds
- as AlexAtNet suggested, you may start the timer more than once, by mistake; so `connected_timer_start` now checks if the timer is not already started